# Belkin Usb-C to ethernet adapter crashes Macbook pro 16"

Tags: macbook-pro, network, catalina, usb, performance

I use the Belkin USB-C to ethernet adapter for my MacBook Pro 16" with macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

When I plug it in, especially after the Mac has rebooted, macOS struggles to perform certain operations (opening apps - bounces forever, showing the dock, etc) - it's just like a freeze but I can still interact with the mouse.

When I plug out the adapter, any outstanding operations are performed instantly.

I should mention, that after a while when the adapter is "warm", everything works as expected. No freezes and I can open Apps as usual.

In every state when the adapter is plugged in, I do have a working internet connection, even when the Mac freezes.

Have any of you experienced the same strange behavior or are there any pitfalls with the hardware and software configuration I could have overlooked?

Comment: This sounds like a faulty adapter.  Try a different one or different brand. I’m partial to [Anker Adapters](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392371/119271)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment :) I tried using an adapter by another manufacturer that works without problems. However, if I use another Belkin adapter (A colleague has the exact same model), I have the same issues as described in my post.

Comment: I'd avoid the Belkin, then